# How do I query a complex JSONB field in Django 1.9

Tags: json, django, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `item` with a field called `data` of type JSONB. I would like to query all items that have text that equals 'Super'.  I am trying to do this currently by doing this:

`Item.objects.filter(Q(data__areas__texts__text='Super'))`

Django debug toolbar is reporting the query used for this is:

`WHERE "item"."data" #> ARRAY['areas', 'texts', 'text'] = '"Super"'`

But I'm not getting back any matching results.  How can I query this using Django?  If it's not possible in Django, then how can I query this in Postgresql?

Here's an example of the contents of the `data` field:

```
{
  "areas": [
    {
      "texts": [
        {
          "text": "Super"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "texts": [
        {
          "text": "Duper"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `Item.objects.filter(data__areas__0__texts__0__text='Super')`

it is not exact answer, but it can clarify some jsonb filter features, also read [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield)

I am not sure what you want to achieve with this structure, but I was able to get the desired result only with strange raw query, it can look like this:

`Item.objects.raw("SELECT id, data FROM (SELECT id, data, jsonb_array_elements(\"table_name\".\"data\" #> '{areas}') as areas_data from \"table_name\") foo WHERE areas_data #> '{texts}' @> '[{\"text\": \"Super\"}]'")`

Dont forget to change `table_name` in query (in your case it should be `yourappname_item`).

Not sure you can use this query in real programs, but it probably can help you to find a way for a better solution.

Also, [there is](http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/) very good intro to jsonb query syntax

Hope it will help you

Comment: `Item.objects.filter(data__areas__0__texts__0__text='Super')` does work, but not what I'm looking for as I want it to search through every element of the arrays.  The raw query is what I'm looking for though so thank you.  Unfortunate that I can't do this using Django, but if cars can drive themselves then I think there's hope ;)

Comment: Cars still can't drive themselves but there's a great blog post that shows how you could use `jsonb_array_elements` in a "Django-way": http://blog.qax.io/django-and-postgres-jsonb-field-beyond-the-basics/ which does not seem to be outdated.